# Error while Initializing Mojarra 2.2.1

Tags: jboss7.x, faces-config, jsf-2.2

I decide to upgrade JSF to 2.2.1 in JBoss 7.1.1 on Java6. I did all migration steps including changing proper jars in server modules folder. I updated pom with proper entries and of course I changed faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

But... when I start server I get:

```
14:45:04,998 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-15) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
14:45:05,035 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-15) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.1 (-SNAPSHOT 20130329-0707 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/trunk@11823) for context '/iCargo'
14:45:06,150 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-15) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:431) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]

14:45:06,159 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/iCargo]] (MSC service thread 1-15) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea]
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:431) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: It is probably environment problem, jboss, faces... I've returned to Mojarra 2.1.X for now. Pity.